# Complex conditional statement to change a specific cell in r

Tags: r

I have a data frame like the following (but with 10,000 rows, and 250 columns):

```
   a b c d e f g
  -------------- 
1| 4 0 6 3 7 3 7
2| 4 6 0 6 6 2 1
3| 3 6 2 6 8 0 5
```

Where I have applied `df$h <- (rowSums(df[, c(1, 2, 4, 6)]))/4` to produce:

```
   a b c d e f g h
  ----------------- 
1| 4 0 6 3 7 3 7 2.5
2| 4 6 0 6 6 2 1 4.5
3| 3 6 2 6 8 0 5 3.75
```

But if there is a 0 in any of the relevant columns, I need that row's h to be 0, i.e.:

```
   a b c d e f g h
  ----------------- 
1| 4 0 6 3 7 3 7 0
2| 4 6 0 6 6 2 1 4.5
3| 3 6 2 6 8 0 5 0
```

I have tried several things such as `df$h[df[, c(7, 8, 10, 18)] == "0"] <- "0"` and some if statements, etc. to no avail.

How can I do that? I have tried methods that first calculate h and then another line to check for if it needs to be changed to 0, but ideally both operations would happen in the same line of code.

Comment: While Maël's answer is a better way to go about it, to expand on the code you have previously tried in your post, a corrected code would be `df$h[apply(df[, c(1,2,4,6)], 1, function(x) any(x == 0))] <- 0 `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following gives `FALSE` if any of there is 0 in any of the column, `TRUE` otherwise. Converted to numeric, it multiplies by 0 when there is at least one 0 and multiplies by 1 otherwise:

```r
!(rowSums(df[, c(1, 2, 4, 6)] == 0) > 0)
#    1     2     3 
#FALSE  TRUE FALSE

(rowSums(df[, c(1, 2, 4, 6)]) / 4) * !(rowSums(df[, c(1, 2, 4, 6)] == 0) > 0)
#  1   2   3 
#0.0 4.5 0.0
```

Or with `ifelse`:

```r
ifelse(apply(df[, c(1, 2, 4, 6)], 1, \(x) any(x == 0)), 0, rowSums(df[, c(1, 2, 4, 6)]) / 4)
```

Or with the very fast (and slightly easier to understand) `Rfast::rowAny`:

```r
(rowSums(df[, c(1, 2, 4, 6)]) / 4) * !Rfast::rowAny(df[, c(1, 2, 4, 6)] == 0)
```

Comment: That's sick, I had no idea you could do that! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

For more flexibility, form your the columns for summing and checking into vectors, then apply them:

```
# Sample dataframe
df <- data.frame(a = c(4,4,3), b = c(0,6,6), c = c(6,2,2), d = c(4,0,2))
      
sum_cols <- c(1,3)
check_cols <- c(2,4)
      
df$e <- rowSums(df[sum_cols])/length(sum_cols) * apply(df[check_cols], 1, FUN = function(x) all(x != 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it was not asked for a `tidyverse` - way, here is one:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- read.table(text = "
a b c d e f g
4 0 6 3 7 3 7
4 6 0 6 6 2 1
3 6 2 6 8 0 5", header = TRUE)

df |>
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(
    total = ifelse(
      any(c_across(c(a, b, d, f)) == 0), 0, sum(c_across(c(a, b, d, f))/4)
    )
  )
#> # A tibble: 3 × 8
#> # Rowwise: 
#>       a     b     c     d     e     f     g total
#>   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <dbl>
#> 1     4     0     6     3     7     3     7   0  
#> 2     4     6     0     6     6     2     1   4.5
#> 3     3     6     2     6     8     0     5   0
```